# Sort only 2 Columns from a Dataframe of 20 Columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have 20 column in a group (dataframe) of 5 rows. I want to force sort only 2 columns and keep others as they are.

I have tried using

```
group2['Col1','Col2'] = group2['Col1','Col2'].sort_values(by=['Col2'])
```

It produces the error

```
return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 108, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1601, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1608, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item

KeyError: ('col1', 'col2')
```

Input and desired output are:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create subset by double `[]` and assign back numpy array:

```
group2 = pd.DataFrame({
         'Col1':list('nyynny'),
         'Col2':[1,3,5,7,2,0],
         'Col3':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'Col4':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'Col5':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'Col6':list('aaabbb')
})
group2[['Col1','Col2']] = group2[['Col1','Col2']].apply(np.sort).values 
print (group2)
  Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5 Col6
0    n     0     4     7     5    a
1    n     1     5     8     3    a
2    n     2     4     9     6    a
3    y     3     5     4     9    b
4    y     5     5     2     2    b
5    y     7     4     3     4    b
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the requirement, i want to sort col1 and col2 independently
col1 = n,n,n,y,y,y
col2  = 0,1,2,3,5,7